# Is it good idea to use "Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false"

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, delegates, event-handling

I have a class that receives data from serialport. i used `action<T> delegate` to pass data to the form where it is displayed in a textbox. the thing is i could not access the `textbox` control, becouse it says: `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on`.

so i set `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false`, and it is working.

is it good idea to do that? or there is a better way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it may appear to work most of the time, it is sure to fail every now and then.

If you need to access/modify the UI control from another thread, use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx).

Comment: Control.Invoke may have handle leak. It`s better to use Control.BeginInvoke instead.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea to do that.

I believe the preferred method is to check to see if Control.InvokeRequired == true, and if so then use Control.Invoke with the proper delegate, which will marshall the method call onto the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Will you write something like below

```
       try
        {
            Object obj=null;
            var result = obj.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {


        }
```

I am sure your answer would be **NO** , similar thing is with Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false, it  will  just eating exception but present unknown results to your estimated clients