# Getting cross thread Error even Used Invoke

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, invoke, ui-thread

Getting cross thread error when executing `tcViewer.TabPages.Add(t)` statement.

Code is as below.

```
Private Function fff(t As TabPage)
    tcViewer.TabPages.Add(t)   'giving cross thread error
End Function

Function WebBrowserThread()
    Dim t As TabPage = New TabPage((k + 1).ToString())
    t.Name = k.ToString()
    tcViewer.Invoke(fff(t))
End Function
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move the creation of the new `TabPage` onto the UI thread as well:

```
Private Function fff(k as Integer)
    Dim t As TabPage = New TabPage((k + 1).ToString())
    t.Name = k.ToString()
    tcViewer.TabPages.Add(t)
End Function

Function WebBrowserThread()
    tcViewer.Invoke(fff(k))
End Function
```

When you construct the `TabPage`, you eventually reach this call stack:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.MarshalingControl.MarshalingControl()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.MarshalingControl.get()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Control(bool autoInstallSyncContext)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.ScrollableControl()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Panel.Panel()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabPage.TabPage()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabPage.TabPage(string text)
```

At this point, the `Handle` is being created, and if you're doing that on the wrong thread, everything else is going to start going wrong (because the thread that the control was created on isn't going to run a message pump)

Answer (score -2):

i don't know what invoking error you get but i suggest disabling cross-thread checking by adding this in the constructor or loaded event (very helpful when dealing with APIs)

```
Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Check this http://tech.xster.net/tips/invoke-ui-changes-across-threads-on-vb-net/

in wpf such problems are easy to fix because you have a single thread for all the controls (`Dispatcher.Invoke`)

## Update

dealing with the UI controls have to be on the UI thread

```
Me.Invoke(sub()
            Dim t As TabPage = New TabPage((k + 1).ToString())
            t.Name = k.ToString()
            fff(t)
          End Sub)




  Me.Invoke(sub()
               tcViewer.TabPages.Add(t)
            End Sub)
```

Comment: In WIN Form, set cross thread checking false , but getting same error as below `Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread.`  Do you know how to use `Invoke` of tab control to add tab page ?

Comment: try this > Me.Invoke(Sub()
                         Dim t As TabPage = New TabPage((k + 1).ToString())
                         t.Name = k.ToString()
                         fff(t)
                     End Sub)

Comment: @bigworld12 If you're going to suggest using CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False then you should also point out that it may lead to apparently random crashes which will be difficult to debug.

Comment: [Is it good idea to use “Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15516014/15498). The answer is no.

Comment: i have been using it for like 4 years until i moved to WPF , not a single crash or bug

Comment: They have a threading bug. Your suggestion is "turn off the feature that made it obvious that you have a threading bug".

Comment: i see it like this : why add 2 more lines of code for a thing that can be done in one line ?

Comment: And putting black tape over the engine warning light is quicker and easier than taking the car to the garage. It doesn't make it the right thing to do.